# Nagios dependancy of services on host state

Tags: nagios

please, how can i configure Nagios when a host get down, in order to get only one alert of host down and not receive the host's services alerts (the rest of alerts)?

Answer (score 0):

Configure your [Host and Service Dependencies](https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagioscore/docs/nagioscore/3/en/dependencies.html) so that Nagios knows which hosts/services are dependent on others.

> Before Nagios executes a service check or sends notifications out for a service, it will check to see if the service has any dependencies. If it doesn't have any dependencies, the check is executed or the notification is sent out as it normally would be. If the service does have one or more dependencies, Nagios will check each dependency entry (...)